# "l'FBI" vs "lo FBI"

Tags: articles, foreign-words

Which one is correct, 1. or 2.?

> 1. 'l'FBI'
> 2. 'lo FBI'

Answer (score 23):

The elision of the article is commonly accepted when the sound of the first letter starts with a vowel (in this case: 'ef-bi-ai'). Thus the first one is correct.

[Accademia della crusca - L'articolo con le sigle](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/larticolo-sigle)

Answer (score 3):

First one seems to be the correct. Example:

[L'Fbi passa da via Moscova per intercettare telefoni e pc](http://www.ilgiornale.it/news/milano/lfbi-passa-moscova-intercettare-telefoni-e-pc-941382.html)